# Create CoordinatorLayot with AppBar expand from bottom

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

How I can make this:

[image]

**But expand from bottom**??? 
I was try `BottomSheetBehavior`, but BottomSheet overlays content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It looks like a `CollapasingToolbarLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"> // added this

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" /> // your content

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Check the samples here:** http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: this example for expand from TOP to BOTTOM, but I want from BOTTOM to TOP like BottomSheetBehavior without overdraw on content.

Comment: this is still an appbar that expands from below =) the added flags are responsible for the display behavior, but not the location